# Typealias and extension function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I need some help understanding the following code as I am complete Kotlin newbie. This is from a kotlin post I found online

```
typealias genericContext<T> = Demo<T>.() -> Unit
class Demo<T> {
    infix fun doThis(block: genericContext<T>) = block()
    fun say(obj: T) = println(obj.toString())
}

fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    val demo = Demo<String>()

    demo doThis { say("generic alias") }
}
```

So I understand that because of the `infix` we can skip the usual method call syntax i.e. `demo.doThis` and do `demo doThis`.
But I don't understand the following:
`typealias genericContext<T> = Demo<T>.() -> Unit`
This seems to associate the string `genericContext<T>` with something that looks like a lambda but I don't get the `.()` part. That extends `Demo` with a function `()`? I am confused on how this works. Could someone shed some light?

Comment: Take a Look at [Function literals with receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54709311/typealias-and-extension-function-in-kotlin)

Comment: @ivw: That is a link to my post

Comment: The `ClassName.()` is the way to declare extension function. Exactly as the link above. 

Kotlin gives you a chance to create a (static) helper function that is possible to call as a member function (but it is only a syntactic sugar).

There are lambda functions in Kotlin too (e.g.. () -> Unit). And it is possible to declare a type of lambda that has another type as the receiver (or `this` for short). 

Lambda with receivers is often used for DSLs and nice to read APIs in Kotlin. You call these lambdas as if they were methods in the code.

The `typealias` is the shortcut, aka C #define

Answer (score 4):

`typealias genericContext<T> = Demo<T>.() -> Unit` is a type alias. It is simply giving a new name to the type on the right hand side. This means that declaration of `doThis` in `Demo` is equivalent to this:

```
infix fun doThis(block: Demo<T>.() -> Unit) = block()
```

Now for the type `Demo<T>.() -> Unit`:
This is a function type. A function of this type takes a `Demo` as it's receiver argument, and returns `Unit`. It is therefore the type of all functions defined either in the `Demo` class or as an extension on the `Demo` class.

When you provide a lambda of this type (for example when you call the `doThis` function), then `this` will point to a `Demo`-object inside the lambda. For example:

```
someDemo.doThis {
    /* "this" is an object of type `Demo`.
     * In this case it's actually "someDemo", because the implementation of "doThis" 
     * calls "block" on the implicit "this".
     */
    this.say("Hey!")
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand `A function of this type takes a Demo as it's receiver,` Do you mean argument? So `()` symbolizes a function that takes `Demo` as argument and returns `Unit`?

Comment: Could you please elaborate that part?

Comment: @Jim The receiver is the object a method is called on. The receiver is bound to `this` in the function body. For example, when you call `"Hello world!".toUpperCase()`, then the string `"Hello world!"` is the receiver.